Null Coalescing Operator not working in Powershell 7
Param(
    [String] $foo
)

$foo ??= "bar" # does not work
$foo = $foo ?? "bar" # does not work
$foo = $foo ? $foo : "bar" # works

write-host $foo

I am using Powershell 7.4.5
What am I doing wrong here?

The operator works just fine, $foo just never happens to be $null

Your parameter is typed string a null value passed as argument to this script will be coerced to empty string and an empty string is never null.

The following script without parameters works just fine:
$foo=$null
$foo ??= "bar"

Write-Host $foo

The problem seems to be the way Powershell handles string parameters in scripts. When omitting a string parameter or setting its default value to $null, Powershell will convert the value to an empty string (see How can I prevent a string argument changing from null to empty when bound to a parameter?).
Consider the following script:
Param(
    [String]
    $foo
)

if ($null -eq $foo) {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is null."
} else {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is not null."
}

if ("" -eq $foo) {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is an empty string."
} else {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is not an empty string."
}

Running the script:
PS C:\src\dummy-6\scripts> .\my-script.ps1 -foo $null
The parameter 'foo' is not null.
The parameter 'foo' is an empty string.


PS C:\src\dummy-6\scripts> .\my-script.ps1
The parameter 'foo' is not null.
The parameter 'foo' is an empty string.
PS C:\src\dummy-6\scripts> 

Even if you set the default value of the parameter to $null it won't work as expected.
Also, the AllowNull validation attribute doesn't work if the type converter is set to string as the string type won't accept a null value.
Changing slightly the script:
Param(
    [String] 
    [AllowNull()]
    $foo=$null
)

if ($null -eq $foo) {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is null."
} else {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is not null."
}

if ("" -eq $foo) {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is an empty string."
} else {
  Write-Host "The parameter 'foo' is not an empty string."
}

Running the script:
PS C:\src\dummy-6\scripts> .\my-script.ps1
The parameter 'foo' is not null.
The parameter 'foo' is an empty string.


PS C:\src\dummy-6\scripts> .\my-script.ps1 -foo $null
The parameter 'foo' is not null.
The parameter 'foo' is an empty string.


If you set it to string, powershell is likely interpreting it as an empty string.
You need to do this
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($foo)) {
    $foo = "bar"
}


Isn't this overkill when something like if (!$foo) {$foo = "bar"} works. Also, the ternary operator also works just fine.
